# Tab delimiter not working in Chrome textarea - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, textarea, keydown

I have a textarea, that I would like to add a tab "\t" to when the user presses the tab key.
My current code is:

```
textarea.onkeydown = function (e) {
  var key = (e.keyCode || e.which);
  if (key == 9) {
    (e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.stopPropogation());
    var s = this.selectionStart;
    var end = this.selectionEnd;
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, s) + "\t" + this.value.substring(end);
    this.selectionStart = end + 1;
  }
};
```

It works fine in Firefox, in IE the text moves around while the tab key is held in, but it adds a tab, however in Chrome nothing happens. I looked at the value property in developer tools, and I see the tabs, but they aren't displayed in the textarea, I can't select the or move the cursor over to them.

Comment: It works fine for me http://jsbin.com/zoretefupika/1/edit

Comment: @VasilVanchuk the JSBin worked for me as well, could the css or font of my textarea some how affect it?

Comment: Maybe. Can you show your case at jsbin?

Comment: @VasilVanchuk (http://jsbin.com/tacagavawuwa/7/edit) it might be something to do with my onkeyup function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code - remove

```
> white-space: nowrap;
```

for textarea

http://jsbin.com/tacagavawuwa/9/

> nowrap    Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace.
>   Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same
>   line until a 
>  tag is encountered
>   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Is there a way I can have the browser not collapse whitespace, but not wrap text onto new line?

Comment: Never mind <textures wrap="off"> is what I really wanted